# Flutter: Getting Instance of 'States' while filtering the json data

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to decode the json data and filter it based on user's input in textformfield.

My model class

```
class States{
  String name;
  String abbreviation;
  States({this.name, this.abbreviation});

  factory States.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> json){
    return States(
      name: json['name'],
      abbreviation: json['abbreviation']
    );
  }
}
```

loading my json asset file,

```
Future loadData() async {
return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/json/states.json');}
```

my json data looks like this,

```
[
{
    "name": "Alabama",
    "abbreviation": "AL"
},
{
    "name": "Alaska",
    "abbreviation": "AK"
},]
```

the function where I'm trying to filter it,

```
Future<void> search(String text) async {
String jsonString = await loadData();
var data = jsonDecode(jsonString);
List<States> states = data.map<States>((value) {
  return States.fromJson(value);
}).toList();
if (textEditingController.text == null ||
    textEditingController.text.isEmpty) {
  streamController.add(null);
  return;
} else {
  streamController.sink.add(states
      .where((element) =>
          element.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(text.toLowerCase())) 
      .toList());
}
```

}

How I'm trying to show it,

```
Container(
              child: StreamBuilder(
                stream: stream,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    return all(context);
                  } else if (snapshot.connectionState == "waiting") {
                    return CircularProgressIndicator();
                  } else {
                    return ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return ListTile(
                            title: Text('${snapshot.data[index]}'), //<--- here
                          );
                        });
                  }
                },
              ),
            )
```

> it show like Instace of 'States' in text widget.

Comment: @pskink thanks for comment, I'm doing that in search() function my problem is when i use where clause it shows instance of 'states' but it does the filtering but it is showing that so that is my problem.

Comment: @pskink oh man thank you it worked. can you tell me what is wrong here? and  I was following a article and a stack query and it never came into my mind that would be problem I was scratching my head from yesterday. thank you again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was simple as told by @pskink I just needed to do this

> Text(snapshot.data[index].name)

instead of this

> Text('${snapshot.data[index]}')